# React scroll Parallax image are jittery on phone

Tags: reactjs, parallax

I have tried to use [React scroll parallax](https://react-scroll-parallax.damnthat.tv/docs/intro) to get the famous scrolling effect on a couple of images which works perfectly fine in chrome, but in safari and I should say on a small screen looks jittery and give the user a bad experience. 
here is a sample project created in stackBitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ybdmbn.
please guide me on how I can improve it or what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the issue by removing the: `speed={-10}` property from the `<Parallax>` tag.
Parallax gets a couple of property which the `speed` and the `translateY` are basically the same thing.

```
    <Parallax translateY={[20, -70]} >
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
        </Parallax>
        <Parallax translateY={[30, -90]} >
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" />
        </Parallax>
      </div>

      <div className={styles.Bottom}>
        <Parallax translateY={[20, -80]} >
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale" />
        </Parallax>
        <Parallax translateY={[40, -80]} >
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/870/200/300?grayscale&blur=2" />
        </Parallax>
      </div>
```